# Is an ally character killed by a Geo Chain count as an Ally Murder

Tags: disgaea

from what i understand on what's required for the good ending, you need to have no ally murders, i try my best to avoid my character being in any line of fire of my own attacks cause it never turns out good if they are.

When i was in the Item World getting Geo Chains to boost up the Bonus Gauge to level up some classes to unlock the newer ones one of my guys (well girl) i accidentally left on a geo panel when the chain started, she was bellow level 5 with no amour so you can imagine what happened.

anyway, i'm wondering if this counts as an ally murder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they do not.

From the Disgaea wiki on [Ally Kills](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Ally_Kill):

> Ally kills do not include:
>
> - Killing Specialists
> - In Disgaea 2 and later, throwing Prinnies or characters killed in the subsequent explosion
> - Throwing an enemy into the Base Panel
> - Making a tower of characters, ending the turn and killing a character with the inflicted damage (in Disgaea 1)
> - Killing a clone
> - **Being killed in a Geo Chain**
> - Being killed by poison , even if inflicted by an attack by the player